# Struts2 namespace changing in redirecting url

Tags: struts2, struts

I have action class which contains application create method, If application save successfully it returns the "success". As you can the my struts.xml I'm redirecting to the the application read only mode. when I am redirecting to the read only action default name space override by the "tenantId"(which is contains in the session)

Here is the redirect url

```
http://localhost:8080/scandium/tenantId/applicationView.html!tenantId?applicationId=40
```

Why is there "!" in url?
How does it change default namespace to "tenantId" ?

Can anyone help me to over come this problem?

```
    <struts>

        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
        <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="html"/>

        <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
             <action name="createApplication" class="com.action.ApplicationAction" method="create">
                        type="tiles">/applicationReadOnlyBody.tiles</result>-->
                        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
                            <param name="actionName">applicationView.html</param>
                           <!-- <param name="namespace">/</param> -->
                            <param name="applicationId">${appId}</param>
                        </result>
                        <result name="input" type="tiles">/new-application.tiles</result>
                </action>

              <action name="applicationView" class="com.action.ApplicationReadOnlyAction" method="viewApplication">
                    <result name="success" type="tiles">/applicationReadOnlyBody.tiles</result>
              </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

Thank you in advance,

Udeshika

Answer (score 0):

Is it your proper struts.xml file? Your struts file seems missing results type for tiles

```
<result-types>
    <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
```

Your struts.xml should look like this:`

```
<struts>

        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
        <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="html"/>

        <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

<result-types>
    <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>

             <action name="createApplication" class="com.action.ApplicationAction" method="create">
                        type="tiles">/applicationReadOnlyBody.tiles</result>-->
                        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
                            <param name="actionName">applicationView.html</param>
                           <!-- <param name="namespace">/</param> -->
                            <param name="applicationId">${appId}</param>
                        </result>
                        <result name="input" type="tiles">/new-application.tiles</result>
                </action>

              <action name="applicationView" class="com.action.ApplicationReadOnlyAction" method="viewApplication">
                    <result name="success" type="tiles">/applicationReadOnlyBody.tiles</result>
              </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

`

And in struts2 redirectAction is changed to redirect. Make changes try it and tell me

Comment: Thank you for the respond,It is already there I have put some part of the struts.xml

Comment: `redirectAction` exists in Struts 2. `redirect` is for url directly and `redirectAction` is for action. See https://struts.apache.org/docs/redirect-action-result.html

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your config. A "floating" type="tiles... and an closed (but never opened) html comment tag.

change this:

```
<action name="createApplication" 
        class="com.action.ApplicationAction" 
        method="create">
        type="tiles">/applicationReadOnlyBody.tiles</result>-->
```

to this:

```
<action name="createApplication" 
        class="com.action.ApplicationAction" 
        method="create">
```

And see if it works or changes in somehow...